# iOS re-order control overlay cell

Tags: ios, listview, reorderlist

When having a black background ListView in iOS and setting the edit property to true, shows the re-order control (white horizontal lines icon) in the right hand side as it should.  It also shows the delete icon on the left side of the cell and then shifts the contents to the right.

The problem is this; the re-order icon overlays the white text of the cell and you can not see the icon.  I know we can't change the background of the re-order control.  What am I missing that the content view is not resized but shifted during the re-order?

[image: Labels inside of contentview]

Comment: You need to make sure your labels and other cell content are added to the cell's `contentView` and not the cell itself.

Comment: @rmaddy like the image above?  if so tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, the content view label was auto sizing to the entire width of the row.  After removing this, the label resizes appropriately.